# How to make event listener synchronous to publish of application event in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have some method which is publishing an application event (MyEvent) and then I am logging "done publishing". The problem I am having is log statement is executed first and then MyEvent listener is getting invoked. How do i make sure execution order is like following:-

1. publish event
2. listen event
3. executing log statement [see code below]

   ```
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void method() {

          //save something in db
         applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new MyEvent(...params));
         log.info("done publishing");
       });

     }

     @TransactionalEventListener
     @Order(2)
     public void handle(MyEvent myEvent) {
       //do something
     }
   ```

Comment: It is a transactional event listener, so it will only be executed on the commit of the method. It is synchronous already.

Comment: @M.Deinum currently event is published-> log statement is executed -> listener is invoked. But I don't want this sequence. I wanted listener to be invoked before log statement

Comment: Then don't make it a transactional event listener but a regular event listener. The default phase for an `@TransactionalEventLIstener` is to execute the received event at the commit. The commit happens after the `method()` has finished executing, which is after publishing the event and do the logging. You could have known all of this when you read the documentation of [`@TransactionalEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html)

Comment: @M.Deinum you are correct. If you will post your comment as an answer then I will accept it. Thank you for explaining so clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`@TransactionalEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html) is an event listener that is bound to the current transaction. It will execute the event at the given phase, the default is `AFTER_COMMIT`.

So in your case the event will be executed after the execution of `method()`. So the event will be fired, but not yet executed by the said listener. Hence the behaviour you see.

The event is in fact, by default, already delivered synchronously and not a-synchronously (which you expect due to the behaviour you see).

If you want to execute the event directly use a regular [`@EventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html) instead of an `@TransactionalEventListener`.

```java
@EventListener
@Order(2)
public void handle(MyEvent myEvent) {
  //do something
}
```

Now the code will behave as you expect and want.